# How to check if boolean is true in custom validation simple-schema in Meteor

Tags: javascript, meteor, meteor-autoform, meteor-collection2, simple-schema

I have the following Schema:

```
Games.attachSchema(new SimpleSchema({
    title: {
        type: String,
        label: "Title",
        max: 30
    },
    multiplayer: {
        type: Boolean,
        label: "Multiplayer",
        denyUpdate: true
    },
    description: {
        type: String,
        label: "Description",
        custom: function() {
            var multiplayer = this.field("multiplayer");
            if (multiplayer.isSet && multiplayer.value && !this.isSet) return "Description is empty!";
            return true;
        }
    }
}));
```

My goal is to check if `description` is empty, but only if the checkbox `multiplayer` has been checked. If the checkbox has not been checked, the `description` should not be mandatory to fill in.

I tried the code above, but it does not validate. Even if I do not have an description and I checked the checkbox, I am able to submit the form.

Comment: I don't know meteor but does the text `"Description is empty!"` display somewhere ? The problem might be the returned string evaluates as `true`. I would try with `return false;` instead as a test case.

Comment: Thank you for your help! According to the [documentation](https://github.com/aldeed/meteor-simple-schema#custom-validation): _Do any necessary custom validation, and return a String describing the error type if you determine that the value is invalid. Any non-string return value means the value is valid._

Comment: What is your form submitting/validation logic ?

Comment: I don't understand your question. My form validation logic is inside my `custom` function.

Comment: OK I wondered if you had other code for validating/submitting the form. I don't know meteor sorry :p

Comment: No problem @PinkTurtle! Thanks anyway. You should check it out! It's a great framework to work with.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/91107/discussion-between-pinkturtle-and-user3475602).

Comment: It's a stupid question but : does your code throw an error ? Forms will typically submit when their JS submit/validation code crashes. I'd look it up in Firefox/Firebug.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the proper [documentation](https://github.com/aldeed/meteor-simple-schema#make-a-field-conditionally-required) and I solved it like this:

```
{
  description: {
    type: String,
    optional: true,
    custom: function () {
      var shouldBeRequired = this.field('multiplayer').value;

      if (shouldBeRequired) {
        // inserts
        if (!this.operator) {
          if (!this.isSet || this.value === null || this.value === "") return "required";
        }

        // updates
        else if (this.isSet) {
          if (this.operator === "$set" && this.value === null || this.value === "") return "required";
          if (this.operator === "$unset") return "required";
          if (this.operator === "$rename") return "required";
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Roughly equivalent to my code I think - except I made a typo :) `this.value != ""` should have been `this.value == ""`.

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is with your validation logic. Try changing it to :

```
if (multiplayer.isSet && multiplayer.value && this.isSet && this.value == "")
return "Description is empty!";
```